# NuGet reference in wrong directory structure

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

My Web2 solution is failing to compile because some of the packages were hosted in a different directory structure to the rest of the solution, and I deleted this structure and the corresponding "packages" folder.

I used Update-Package -reinstall

Hoping that this would fix it... however it still kicks out this error message on build:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props
```

Now as far as I can tell all the references should be OK, packages.config says:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" />
```

And the directory structure exists

```
--Solution Dir
 |-- packages
   |--Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0
```

I tried updating the package and got version 1.3.2, but the error message remained the same, ie version 1.0.0 was missing.

Theres' clearly some reference to this floating around somewhere - but I don't know where to start looking. I'm assuming the ..\packages in the path indicates its looking for the package in the external directory location (as one up was where the original packages were)

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I copied the packages folder back to its original location outside the solution directory and .... the issue isn't resolved. So maybe that was never the issue in the first place.

However the error message is still reporting a missing NuGet package that to all appearances is actually there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This StackOverflow answer got me started on the right track, once I Googled the error message without the ..\ in front of the package location

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32296184/1286358

Then I had to go through and add serveral missing references - presumably because in my hacking attempts to fix the issue I had removed them then not re-referenced them.