# Nuget packages are not restored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I cloned project from Gitub. My solution has 6 projects and every project has packages.config file (which has listing of packages along with their versions) but these packages are not restored.

**Methods I already tried to restore nuget packages:**

1. In Visual Studio: `Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manger -> General` and checked both options.
2. Write Following Code in `web.config` file:

`<packageRestore>
    <!-- The 'enabled' key is True when the "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" checkbox is set.
             Clearing the box sets this to False, disabling command-line, automatic, and MSBuild-Integrated restore. -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>`

This restored packages for that project, but other projects don't have web.config file.

3. Added following code in `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`:

`<configuration>
    <packageRestore>
        <!-- The 'automatic' key is set to True when the "Automatically check for missing packages during
             build in Visual Studio" checkbox is set. Clearing the box sets this to False and disables
             automatic restore. -->
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
</configuration>`
([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore))

4. Run this command in Package Manager Console: `Update-Package –reinstall`
   It said this for all the packages:

`Package 'Abp.2.1.2' already exists in project 'TempABP5.Migrator'
Successfully installed 'Abp 2.1.2' to TempABP5.Migrator`

5. Created a `NuGet.Config` file next to your `.sln` file, containing:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <packageSources>
       <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
       <add key="aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease" value="https://www.myget.org/f/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/" />
     </packageSources>
   </configuration>`

([source](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html))

6. Tested by removing following code from `.csproj` file:

`<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
</Target>`  ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101739/3952692))

But still I cannot restore packages and project fails to build. How can I restore missing packages?

**Updated:**

Below image contains the screen shot of project and errors:[image]

I deleted all data in bin/obj folders and then clean solution and then build but same errors..

Then I again run the command `Update-Package –reinstall` to make sure that packages already exists and the result is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is hard for us to find the solution without any log or screenshot for restore fail and build fail. So would you mind sharing us some log of failed result? Besides, according to the result of method 4, the package already exists in project, what is your basis for determining the failure of package restore?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I have updated question, please have a look.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution, deleting all obj/bin folders? Intellisense is sometimes showing wrong information based on some cache.

Comment: @IrfanYusanif, If you can confirm that the command Update-Package –reinstall is successful for all packages, especially, Abp.Web.Mvc & Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc. What Erno said would be a possibility, you can try it. And you can check if the references are correct in the Reference.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, Leo, I have updated question, please have a look. Packages issue happens to me for almost all projects downloaded from github.

Comment: @Irfan Yusanif, Thanks for your update. Is this "Packages" under git version control? If yes, please try to use the .gitignore file to have Git ignore the contents of the packages folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control

Comment: @Leo-MSFT, thank you! I added `.gitignore` file and it worked but only for new created repository. What else I have to do to make it work for existing project?

Comment: @IrfanYusanif, Glad to know that help to you. But I`m not very clear about your problem " What else I have to do to make it work for existing project?" Is this issue also occurred on the existing project? Or you just want use .gitignore file for existing project? As a recommendation, you can post a new question with more detail info, much more communities willing to see your problem.

Comment: I created new project just to make sure that `.gitignore` file is working but I need it to work for my existing project! so I pasted same file in existing project (My original project which doesn't have package issues) and after commiting code and then downloading project it still gives same errors.

Comment: Whether the Package folder exists after download project(Before restore)? If yes, delete the package folder, then restore the packages.

Comment: Deleting the package folder do the trick! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Install failed. Rolling back... Package "A" does not exist in the
>   project. Package "A" already exist in the folder.

That because the "Packages" folder under git version control. You should **use the .gitignore file to have Git ignore the contents of the packages folder.**

For the detail info, you can refer to the [Omitting NuGet packages in source control systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control).

Hope this can help you.