# VS2017 cannot discover MSTest tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I've been having this recurring problem with some of my .Net framework 4.5 and 4.6 and 4.7 projects not having their tests discovered by test explorer. The "tests" log output is showing:

`The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)`

That's all the info I have.

I've tried pretty much every combination of the different version of `MSTest.Framework` and adapter and such. Just can't figure this one out. I've done the Test Extension cache clearing.

Comment: If you have Enterprise, changing Live Unit Testing's logging level to Verbose (Tools > Options > Live Unit Testing) and enabling it for the test class can offer some additional information about the failure.

Comment: Did you import Code project namespace into test project?

Comment: Running into the same issue, tried recreating the test project as well and no luck.

Comment: @Eric I did that. The tests appeared when enabling Live Unit Testing. And then disappeared when disabling it.

Answer (score 8):

I had upgraded some of the projects to 4.6.2 and two of them had app.config files with specific assembly bindings.

Deleting both the app.config files fixed the problem for me - there were no other settings being used in the files so I just deleted rather than fixing the bindings.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. I am using VS 2017 and .Net Version 4.7. Though I made test runnable by adding Visual Studio Quality Tools and by removing MSTest framework and adapter packages, I am getting other issues like "Could not load System.Runtime"

**Update:** In my case, the root cause of getting this issue was deleting the `<Target>` tag in the test project's .csproj file. I got missing file nuget package error and resolved that issue as suggested  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101739/1661861). Unfortunately it has a side effect that made my test methods non discover-able

Answer (score 0):

In my case an error in my `app.config` xml format prevented to discover and run tests on that test project.
It is actually weird though, that the error was this one instead of malformed configuration...