# Nuget cannot restore Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to install/restrore `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0` in VS 2017 using Nuget Package Manager. In the output it shows restore completed. however when i check the `packages` folder i dont see `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` folders.
And beacuse of that i get error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
>   this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ....\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props. XXXXX\Src\Api\Api.csproj    296

In csproj file there is a line at the top

```
<Import Project="..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

**Background**
This issue is occurring in Web API project with target framework 4.6.2. 
I also have `NET Standard 1.4` library that i want to share with different types of .NET application. When i add reference of `NET Standard Library` to Web API project i got [missing dependencies issues](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/901). So as per the suggestion i edited .csproj file and added

```
  <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

That fixed the missing dependencies issue.

Then i deleted `package.config` file, removed all packages from `packages` folder and added back all the packages (except i could not add Microsoft.Net.Compilers). The package reference is now in .csproj file

There [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254439/nuget-packages-are-missing) post here, however in my case `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` does not even getting restored to `packages` folder. VS 2017 shows restored is complete but i don't know where its actually coping the files. (unless the folder name is different than Microsoft.Net.Compilers)

My original package.config file has this line

```
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" developmentDependency="true" />
```

now in .csproj file i have

```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

**UPDATE 1**
So it looks like when packagereference is enabled nuget will install the packages at `C:\Users\{username}\.nuget\packages` folder

that means i need to update csproj file with correct relative path.

What would be the relative path here for packages folder?

Comment: Since I had trouble with this nuget, I have just removed it from project file, and now it compiles.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since setting the Package Management Format to PackageReference installs the packages to global nuger folder that is `C:\Users\{username}\.nuget\packages` i had to edit csproj file update the following lines

**top of csproj**

```
<Import Project="$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform\1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform\1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers\2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

**and then update the following lines at the bottom of csproj**

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers\2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers\2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform\1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform\1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
  </Target>
```

All of this is just to reference `NET Standard 1.4` project into .NET 4.6.2. very annoying!!

Comment: There are actually variables to reference this package location. Have a look at `obj\projectName.csproj.nuget.g.props`

Answer (score 5):

@LP13's answer got me pointed into the correct direction. Although I had to do something different.

My .csproj file have 2 references to Microsoft.Net.Compliers. One for 2.9.0 (current one I'm using) and 1.2.1 (old version).

At the top of the file I commented out the 2 Import Project lines that referenced:

- Import Project=".\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.1 ...
- Import Project=".\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.2.1 ...

At the bottom of the file, do the same in the Error Condition entries for the same refrences:

- Error Condition="!Exists('.\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.2.1...
- Error Condition="!Exists('.\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.1' ...

Comment: This was perfect, hopefully i'll be able to remember this years later when i hit it again!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had downloaded a project from GitHub which did not include the full sln, but was just a single folder with .csproj and packages folder on the same level.

In this case I simply had to replace "..\packages\" with ".\packages\" in the .csproj file. I assume the owner of the GitHub repo decided to only upload the project folder, but didn't recompile to test before uploading... maybe?

Comment: I had to change it from `..\..\packages\ `  to `..\packages\ `  in the .csproj file to make it work.

Comment: This option did not work for me, but Jeff's answer above did the trick.