# Missing NuGet packages when used on project within a solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget

I've looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32296184/4572356):

> Editing the .csproj file and correcting the relative path to the
>   solution folder (which contains the packages folder) solved the
>   problem for me.

but I'm not sure what to edit.

I'm making a C++ project in Visual Studio 2013. I have one solution with three projects. One of the projects needs a NuGet package.

I used *Manage NuGet packages for solution* on my solution to install the NuGet package. From there I selected the one project which needs the package. I also used *Enable NuGet Package Restore*.

By doing this I end up with a *.nuget* and *packages* folder in the solution directory.

When I try to build the project requiring the package I get the error:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ....\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets.

If I follow the mentioned path, assuming that the directory it is relative from is the project directory of the project, the "missing file" is there.

The project having this problem, was a project I used alone (with its own solution) before, and has been copy pasted to this solution with three projects.
That's why I mentioned the answer of an another question and the top of the post. That answer suggest editing a project file. If I open my .vcxproj file I see this:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
    <Import Project="..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" />
    <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
    <Import Project="..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" />
    <Import Project="..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

I'm very unsure what to edit.

I can guess that maybe some of the paths should be changed from being relative of the project directory, to being relative of the solution directory. But by editing to:

```
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
    <Import Project="packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" />
    <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
    <Import Project="packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" />
    <Import Project="packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Visual studio will give me an error stating: *An item with the same key has already been added*. The project is then marked as *(load failed)* in the solution browser.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My problem was solved with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101739/4572356).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101739/4572356).

In the .vcxproj file I removed the following:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.winapp.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

and I can now build the project.

It is probably not the best solution, as there is a reason for these Error Conditions to exist. But editing the paths did not help.