# no test available..test through exe using build tools and test agent on VM

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

I am trying to run an all included exe (created using Costura ) on a windows VM. As per an answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402899/can-i-use-mstest-exe-without-installing-visual-studio) , I have installed test agent and build tools and trying to run exe through this command

`C:\Users\..\Desktop>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" MyExeName.exe /Tests: MyTestName`

on VM , I start the agent and give above command but I am receiving error `No test is available in C:\Users\..\Desktop\MyExeName.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.`

The exe runs fine on local machine using same command and start tests.  On local I have VS2019 and all the code. On VM , I can not have VS and code base as a requirement.

**EDIT:** 
      I noticed (through ILSpy) that in dot exe under references, there is no reference to this `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll` , however the `dll` is present in resources.

Comment: Anyone on this please?

Comment: You could use the /ListDiscoverers and /ListExecutors arguments to find the test discoverer and executors on the VM. Just to rules some things out.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019#general-command-line-options

Comment: @Kevin When I run that , I do not see `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter` package, however I see `Default Executor Uri: executor://mstestadapter/v1` but package listed for this is different  `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.MSTestDiscoverer`

Comment: So it seems that reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter` is indeed the issue for not discovering tests. How can I include that reference and not break it when create an exe, any idea?

Comment: Try to add MSTest.TestAdapter as a package https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter/

Comment: @Kevin , thanks for your response . When I compared the out put of this command `vstest.console.exe MyExeName.exe \ListExecutors \ListDiscoverers ` for local and the VM (where I am having issue) , it looks same. In that sense, it seems it is not a referencing issue. Can you think of anything else , why I cant run exe on VM through `vstest.console`

Comment: How does your output folder look like on the VM? Your platform is set to 'Any Cpu'? Are you using the same framework version on your local machine as on the VM?

Comment: @Kevin I am not sure how to check out put folder because , I am running an exe (created by Costura.Fody package) on VM. Yes, when I build/create exe , I see that platform is set 'Any CPU' .  I checked, I have .NET Framework 4.8 on both local and VM. And my solution is targeting Framework 4.7.2 in project properties

Comment: Do you think it has to do something with test agent and test controller setup? When I started , I installed Test Agent and  Build Tools as per an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402899/can-i-use-mstest-exe-without-installing-visual-studio) . I am able to run command though, using `vstest.console` located here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\T
estAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`

Comment: Can you share your test class? I will install a test agent on my VM so I can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this error... I did some experiments on my csproj file and it turns out you have to add an Import tag in your console csproj file. This has nothing to do with your test agent or test class.

Check your package.config (ps. this is 2019, so check your version) MSTest.TestAdapter has to be added.

```
<package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Secondly, add the Import tag to your csproj file. (and again check your version)

```
<Import Project="..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props')" />
```

[image: ProjectFile]

When importing this project a few more items are being added to your project.

[image: Props]

And this results into this output

[image: Output]

See screenshots below for test case 1 (not working) and 2 (working)

Test 1:
[image: Test1]

Test 2:
[image: Test2]

I hope this is working on your end!!

Solution and project:
[image: solution]

Comment: I was able to get past that error by help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629647/no-xunit-tests-discovered-by-vstest-console-exe) i.e by passing /TestAdapterPath in command line. However , I would like to not pass that parameter and somehow build everything into exe. As per your answer , I looked and both of these lines are already there in my project.  `<package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />`

Comment: And `<Import Project="packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props" Condition="Exists('packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props')" />` , If you have any idea how to build everything into exe , I would be glad to accept answer :)

Comment: My answer was based on only a console application. I will update my answer with a screenshot of my solution.